# exe built with python on virtual window cannot connect to remote mariadb

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, window

I'm trying to run exe file written by python on virtual window server(Windows 10 8 Core) and connect to remote mariadb installed on linux(Cent OS 7).

In my local environment, it successfully connects to the mariadb but on virtual window server it doesn't.

Below is the exception message printed on cmd console in virtual window server.

```sh
pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
```

And another below is the python code i used for building exe file.

```py
import argparse, socket, time, json, platform, psutil, requests, pprint, uuid, math, pymysql

def main():
  
    conn = pymysql.connect(host="221.168.38.108",
                           port=17011,user="root",
                           password="mypassword",
                           db="dbname")
    print("Connected Successfully")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE" 
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print(results)
    conn.close()
    print("Connection closed")
    
    # omitted unneeded another codes


while True:
    main()
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")
    time.sleep(args.interval)
```

Here is the code in spec file as a result of pyinstaller command

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['monitor.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='monitor',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

Comment: You also need to say which tool you used to you used to wrap the Python in an `.exe` and show the code (such as a `.spec` file) or command you provided to it.

Comment: I used pyinstaller to wrap the python code 
(pyinstaller --onefile monitor.py)

Also, I just copied the exe file built as the result of the command to the virtual window server and run it on the cmd.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the right code you asked but updated the original post with code in spec file I found